# Как передать список в аргументы функции?

Tags: c#, nunit

Предположим, что есть такая функция:

```
public List<MyClass01> Read(string _name)
{
    List<MyClass01> x = new List<MyClass01>();

    foreach (var item in my)
    {
        if (item.name == _name)
        {
            x.Add(item);
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

Как в нее можно передать значение списка извне?
Необходимо для проведения тестирования в NUnit.

Вот такой вариант теста должен быть на выходе:

```
[Test()]
public void Test1()
{
    int[] theArray = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    int actual = Class1.MyClass01.Что-тотутдолжнобыть();
    int expected = 1;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Где "Что-тотутдолжнобыть" необходимо обратится к вышеописанной функции и передать в нее список.
Вопрос наверное элементарный, но я на него потратил уже не один день.

Полный код класса:

```
public class MyClass01
    {
        public MyClass01(string _name, int _kol)
        {
            name = _name;
            kol = _kol;
        }
        public string name;
        public int kol;
    }

    static List<MyClass01> my1;// = new List<MyClass01>();
    static List<MyClass01> my2;// = new List<MyClass01>();

    public class cAAA
    {
        List<MyClass01> my = new List<MyClass01>();
        public cAAA()
        {
            my.Add(new MyClass01("aaa", 1));
            my.Add(new MyClass01("bbb", 2));
            my.Add(new MyClass01("aaa", 3));
            my.Add(new MyClass01("ccc", 4));
        }
        //            public void Read(string _name, ref List<MyClass01> x)
        public List<MyClass01> Read(string _name)
        {
            List<MyClass01> x = new List<MyClass01>();

            foreach (var item in my)
            {
                if (item.name == _name)
                {
                    x.Add(item);
                }
            }
            return x;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Метод у Вас принимает в качестве параметра `string`, так что передать в него `List` не получится. Или Вы хотите определить некое значение для переменной `my`, из которой заполняется результат? Но по коду абсолютно непонятно, где она определяется и где заполняется. Кроме того, в тесте отсутствует вызов метода `Read`, так что зачем Вы его вообще привели - непонятно. Или этот  метод должен стоять на месте `Что-тотутдолжнобыть()`? Но тогда не видно инициализации экземпляра (метод-то не статический). В общем, объясните подробнее - что за список и куда его передать.

Comment: @Zufir "Или этот метод должен стоять на месте Что-тотутдолжнобыть()? Но тогда не видно инициализации экземпляра (метод-то не статический)." Именно так и есть. Я класс как таковой привел просто в пример, это не конкретно нужный мне (по этому он может быть неправильный). Я пытаюсь понять, как можно протестировать список, а именно с помощью теста передать список в функцию.

Comment: @S.Stuart что такое `my` в методе `Read`? это какое-то существующее поле? какой именно список нужно "передать" в функцию? my? или x? Вообще в функцию можно передеть только то, что она принимает параметром. Сделайте тот список, который надо передать, параметром. Это решит проблему?

Comment: @PashaPash добавил полный код класса.

Comment: @S.Stuart ок. какой из списков вы хотите передать? `x` или `my`? Теперь по коду понятно что происходит, осталось понять что вам нужно получить.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментарию в коде, вы пытаетесь передать список `x`. Для написания теста это не нужно - метод и так возвращает вам список `x`, так что можно просто проверить его содержимое:

```
[Test()]
public void Test1()
{
    // вроде бы не нужнен для тестирования этого метода
    int[] theArray = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

    // у вас нестатический метод, для вызова нужен экземпляр
    var instance = new Class1.MyClass01.cAAA(); 

    // судя по коду, должен вернуть список из одного элемента
    List<Class1.MyClass01> actualList = instance.Read("aaa");

    // проверить, что элемент 1
    Assert.AreEqual(1, actualList.Count);

    int actual = actualList.Single().kol; // извлечь элемент
    int expected = 1;
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: Почему`int actualList`, ведь в оригинале `int actual`  то есть скорее всего получается что-то вроде `int actual = instance.Read("aaa")[0].kol;`, но при этом непонятно зачем нужен `theArray`.

Comment: @Stawros подправил тип. мне тоже непонятно зачем нужнен `theArray`. Для написания теста на `Read` он не нужен, я бы просто удалил его.

Comment: @PashaPash спасибо за то что помогаете! theArray был у меня списком для удобства и я определил его отдельно, но потом он оказался аппендиксом и по этому просто забыл его удалить:) 
Попробовал Ваш тест, но почему-то в строке 'List<int> actualList = instance.Read("aaa");' выдает исключение о неверном преобразовании типа (Неявное преобразование типа '"System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApplication1.Class1.MyClass01>" в "System.Collections.Generic.List<int>"' невозможно).

Comment: @S.Stuart подправил.

Comment: @PashaPash Я наконец разобрался с вашей помощью как нужно было делать:) Осталась последняя проблема - при реквесте "aaa" выдает в итоге двойку, а не свойственную ей единицу. Не улавливаю почему. А если задать bbb, то выдает единицу. Хмм.

Comment: @S.Stuart ну значит не зря тест писали )). берите отладичик и идите по шагам.